# FCM topic messages not received in iOS

Tags: php, firebase, push-notification, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM topic messages to send messages. Everything was working fine until I change the name of topic. 
  I was using the topic "mytest" . Later some day I have changed the topic name to "mytest-qa".
  Both ios and android apps are subscribed to topic "mytest-qa". but the messages are getting received in ios , but getting  in Android.
  Here is my payload.

```
                'to'      => $topic,
                'notification'  => $msg,
                "priority" => "high",
                "data" => array('screen_id' =>$id)
```

I am using curl to send notifications, it gives me messaged_id as response.

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Have resolved this by adding title to the message.

```
$msg = array
              (
                'body'  => $body.' ',
                'title' => $title,
                'icon'  => 'new'
            );
```

Comment: At first try to send this message by firebase console to the topic.
If iOS still did not receive it, then maybe you didn't register device to this topic.

Comment: I did verified from firebase console, iOS received messages of firebase console. Thanks!

Comment: Okay... but it didn't solve your problem?

Comment: I had removed the header for a message as part of a requirement. As this was blank, the message was not sent to firebase for it to send it to iOS device. Have resolved this by adding header to the message.

Comment: @KV90 Could you share how you solved this please? How did you add the header?

Comment: $msg = array
           (
    'body'  => $body.' ',
    'title' => $title,
             'icon' => 'new'
         );

 $firebaseChannel = '/topics/'.$this->firebase_channel;
$fields = array
(
    'to'      => $firebaseChannel,
    'notification'  => $msg,
    "priority" => "high",
    "data" => array('screen_id' =>$screen_id)
);